# PowerShell installation folder and script filename extension across versions

Tags: powershell, versioning

Wikipedia says that [PowerShell 2.0](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell) was distributed with Windows 7; so as I use Windows 7, I'm obviously using that version.

But that raises two questions:

1. Why is PowerShell's folder `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0` with that trailing `v1.0` when it actually should be `v2.0`?
2. Why is the PowerShell script extension `.ps1`? Will that extension increment when the version changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simply the result of a choice made by the Powershell team.  They decided to keep both the 1.0 directory and the .ps1 extension for V2 of powershell.

The best way to actually check the version of Powershell is to use the expression `$PSVersionTable.PSVersion`

```
C:\Users\jaredpar> $PSVersionTable.PSVersion

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
2      0      -1     -1
```

Answer (score 1):

[This is an ancient blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2007/11/02/ctp-versioning/) (2007), but it still applies; in short:

- **As long as new PowerShell versions remain *backward-compatible*, they will *replace* earlier versions**:

  - The installation location, reflected in `$PSHOME` - `$env:systemroot\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0` - will remain the same.
  - The filename extension - `.ps1` - will remain the same.
- Scripts created for an earlier version will continue to run.
- **To mark a script as requiring version `<n>` *at a minimum* , use `#requires -version <n>`** at the top of the script (technically, it can be placed *anywhere* in the script, but it makes sense sense to place it at the top).

**In *Windows PowerShell*, backward compatibility has been maintained since v1** (current is v5.1 as of this writing - likely the *last* major version; see below), so both the installation location and the filename extension have remained the same.

However, **all future effort will go toward the separate, cross-platform PowerShell *Core* edition**, which - as of v6.2.0 - is *largely* backward-compatible with Windows PowerShell, though its use of .NET *Core* as the foundation means that certain Windows-specific technologies are fundamentally unavailable - see [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2017/07/14/powershell-6-0-roadmap-coreclr-backwards-compatibility-and-more/).

---

To **get the current session's PowerShell version**:

```
PS> [string] $PSVersionTable.PSVersion
5.1.14393.693   # PSv5.1 example
```

More generally, hashtable **`$PSVersionTable`**, introduced in v2, contains several pieces of version information, (incompletely) described in [`Get-Help about_Automatic_Variables`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables); *WinPS* below refers to *Windows PowerShell*, whereas *PSCore* refers to PowerShell *Core*:

*Shared* properties:

```
Name                           Value                                                                                                                           
----                           -----                                                                                                                           
PSVersion                      5.1.14393.693 # The PowerShell version.                                                                                                             
PSEdition                      Desktop       # 'Desktop'=WinPS; 'Core'=PSCore
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...} # array of compatible versions                                                                                                         
WSManStackVersion              3.0              # WS-Management (WinRM) version                                                                                                           
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3              # remoting-protocol version                                                                                                               
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1          # serialization-protocol version
```

Additional properties *exclusive to WinPS*:

```
BuildVersion                   10.0.14393.693   # ?? Highest supported OS major.minor version, seemingly followed by the build.revision PS version.
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000  # The .NET Framework CLR version
```

Additional properties *exclusive to PSCore*:

```
GitCommitId                    6.2.0 # The Git commit ID reflecting an RTM tag (e.g., 6.2.0), release tag (e.g., 6.2.0-rc.1) or a specific non-release commit (e.g., 6.2.0-preview.4-108-g5d54f1aa3871a826409496437e25856dc263ccc4)
OS                             Microsoft Windows 10.0.17134 # [System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation]::OSDescription
Platform                       Win32NT  # [System.Environment]::OSVersion.Platform
```